# images are not displaying in gmail using amazon ses in laravel

Tags: image, laravel, amazon-ses, laravel-mail

In my gmail it's not showing images which are sent via amazon ses, src url is correct(when I'm checking this in browser it's showing image), but in mail body it's not displaying. when I checked this in console it's showing like this,

```
<img style="width:323px" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/naWskMotv2jP1vN2knNrRVXIvf9Ag_yZDgbY_kNxYIHHESVA1PJYZZLQsuMBiX-3S8ynkx9PsZejRQQDcU3OVY1uMezb72Mum_JX71f59TlLDHoI=s0-d-e1-ft#MYFILEPATH" class="CToWUd">
```

Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

@r-chiranjeevi Did you solve this?

[Things to try](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/qFKEW_27A5Y):

> I'd recommend checking if the image is set to be set to 'publicly visible'.
>
> Please refer to this help article on '[Gmail signatures](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8395?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop)'.

Or move the image to Amazon S3

It seems you [already tried the following without success](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/images-are-not-displaying-in-gmail-using-amazon-ses-in-laravel):

> I'd recommend checking if the image is set to be set to **'publicly visible'**. Additionally Gmail caches the images it receives in emails, hence the googleusercontent.com domain. Also did you **fill in the #MYFILEPATH** as they should be *your original path to your image on Amazon*.